# update data from another table postgresql using IN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables :table1 and table2.When using this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a 
WHERE a.name IN (SELECT name FROM table2 )
```

The result is 20.

When I want update data based on this query

```
UPDATE table1 SET number='1' 
FROM table1 a 
WHERE a.name IN (SELECT name FROM table2)
```

The result is all the number will be set to 1 instead of only 20.The default number is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET number=1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: found the answer.
UPDATE table1 SET number='1' 
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM table2)